# How to limit number of characters typed in Short Description in the Admin Panel?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, product-attribute, validation

Is it possible to limit the number of characters typed on the Short Description text area in the Admin Panel?

My Magento version is 1.9.3.1 .

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the number of chars with using Magentos "form validation" JS. Therefor you have to add two CSS classes to short descriptions input field.

Either you set `validate-length maximum-length-{MAX}` to `eav_attribute` `frontend_class` database column or you add on observer to product edit page ...

> app/code/local/Your/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_prepare_form>
            <observers>
                <test>
                    <model>your_module/observer</model>
                    <method>setProductShortDesctiptionMaximumLength</method>
                </test>
            </observers>
        </adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_prepare_form>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

> app/code/local/Your/Module/Model/Observer.php

```
/**
 * @const int
 */
const MAX_LENGTH = 250;

/**
 * @return void
 */
public function setProductShortDesctiptionMaximumLength(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $form = $observer->getForm();
    if ($element = $form->getElement('short_description')) {
        $element
           ->setClass('validate-length maximum-length-' . self::MAX_LENGTH)
           ->setNote('Maximum ' . self::MAX_LENGTH . ' chars');
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, but downvoted for:  
 1) not using php doc
 2) not using translations for notes  
 3) not using chain call for $element methods  
 4) not semantic method name

Comment: Okay ... my downvote was not offensive, but this ... 1) just posted relevant code ... yep w/o doc block 2) notes in Mage core are also not translateted 3) does it make a difference? 4) i use "test" in most cases, because everbody should name mehtods as he like ... EDIT: update code w/o tranlation ...

Comment: Don't get me wrong ... it is just if you can avoid a rewrite, you should do. Your method also works, but if possible using an observer IS the better way. So i really do not understand you downvote ... if you think about it, it should be +1  :/ EDIT: i could downvote w/o a comment, but i didnt ...

Comment: Totally agree that approach with rewrite is more acceptable. But since you decided to criticize working solution, I left some reasonable criticism to your solution. Regarding to translations, it is good to use them in admin too, since there is a language switcher in the admin

Comment: Now the code looks better, so it can be up voted

Answer (score -1):

Add a new file to your module *Adminhtml_Product_Attributes* with the following code in it:

```
<?php

/**
 * Class Company_ModuleName_Block_Adminhtml_Product_Attributes
 */
class Company_ModuleName_Block_Adminhtml_Product_Attributes
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Attributes
{
    /**
     * @const int
     */
    const MAXIMUM_LENGTH = 250; // or whatever value you need

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        parent::_prepareForm();
        $form = $this->getForm();
        if ($element = $form->getElement('short_description')) {
            $element->setClass('validate-length-' . self::MAXIMUM_LENGTH);
            $this->setForm($form);
        }
    }
}
```

Then define a rewrite in your *config.xml*:

```
<blocks>
    <adminhtml>
        <rewrite>
            <catalog_product_edit_tab_attributes>Company_ModuleName_Block_Adminhtml_Product_Attributes</catalog_product_edit_tab_attributes>
        </rewrite>
    </adminhtml>
</blocks>
```

Comment: Downvoted b/c of unnecessary rewrite.